# Converting negative binary to decimal

Tags: c, binary

I have been trying for the past several hours to convert a negative binary with the first bit as 1 to a decimal. The twos complement conversion seems to be impossible but I believe there has to be some easier way to do this because this is just the beginning of a beginner class in C.

```
int power;
int count = 0;
int length = strlen(value);
int result = 0;
int negResult = 0;
int i = length - 1;
int j;

if (value[0] == '1') {
  for (; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (value[i] == '1')
    result += 1;
    result << 1;
  }
  printf("%d\n", result);
  result = ~result;
  result += 1;
  printf("%d\n", result);
  for (j = 8; j > 0; j--) {
    if (result << (8-j) == 1) {
      power = (int) pow(2,count);
      negResult += power;
    }
    count++;
  }

  printf("-%d\n", negResult);
}
else {
  for (; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (value[i] == '1') {
      power = (int) pow(2,count);
      result = result + power;
    }
    count++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", result);
}
}
```

I pass it:

```
binary_to_decimal("10011011");
```

and I get 5 then -5 and then -0 for each `printf`.

I did not include the code that actually converts it to a decimal since for positive binaries it works fine and I believe once the twos complement works it should work for negative binaries as well.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here, it's hard to know where to start. temp, temp2, and temp3 are uninitialized, and you cannot append to them with `+=` ... that just changes the value of the pointer (to some other undefined value).

Comment: `if (value[0] == '1') { for (i=1; i<length; i++) { result <<= 1;  if (value[i] == '1') result += 1; }` and drop the `for (j = 8; j > 0; j--) {` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be clear about what `temp += '0'` is doing. It's not making a string, rather it's offsetting an uninitialized pointer and is the cause of the segfault when you come to actually use it as in `temp2[j]`. To work with strings like I think you're wanting to, check out `strcat()`.

I would junk this and start over. Don't manipulate chars in strings, just convert the string to a binary. Write some code to walk the input string from the first character towards the last. Keep a `result` integer for your answer, initially `0`. As you walk through the string, shift `result << 1`, and then if you see a char `'1'`, add a number `1` to `result`. If you see a `'0'` in the string don't add anything, but in either case do the left shift first.

This will get you a binary of however many bits you have. For negative numbers (topmost (first) bit = '1') you will need to sign extend by OR-ing '1' into all the bits above the sign bit, bitwise-invert the result and add 1. Check this on paper to see how it works, and be aware the input string can't be too long. Good luck with the class.

```
int length = strlen(value);
unsigned int result = 0;
unsigned int signExtend;
unsigned int negResult = 0;

// assemble incoming chars as bits in an unsigned int
for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    result = result << 1;
    if (value[i] == '1')
        result += 1;
    }
printf("0x%x, %d\n", result, result); // see it is a hex number and a decimal

// if negative, convert to positive number
if (value[0] == '1') {
    // first, sign-extend
    signExtend = (1 << (length-1));
    signExtend -= 1;
    signExtend = ~signExtend;
    result |= signExtend;
    printf("signExtend mask = 0x%x, sign-extended number = %x\n", signExtend, result);

    // then, two's complement
    negResult = ~result;
    negResult += 1;

    // show the result with the '-' sign explicitly added:
    printf("result is -%d\n", negResult);

    // but actually, once you have sign extended,
    // you can cast the result as signed and just print it:
    printf("result as signed int = %d\n", (int)result);
} else {
    // positive result, just print it
    printf("result is %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. However, I am now getting a wrong answer as I mentioned above. I changed the code to reflect my interpretation of what you are saying. If you can let me know what is wrong, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the first loop should walk from MSB to LSB, not as I originally wrote it the other way around. One error is the left shift result is discarded, and it should occur before the bit is added in not after. I don't like the look of the sign-extend code. Here is something that works and which tries to show what is happening.

Comment: Thanks. The code worked. But if you could just answer some questions, that would be appreciated. When putting the code into result in the first for loop, it is just putting one in that bit place, right? It's not actually adding the value of one, right? Also, why does the left shift occur first? Lastly, what is the purpose the sign extension if result has the same number of bits as value? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Putting a one into the LSB which was previously zero is exactly the same as adding one. the shift operation multiplies everything by two. The first bit you put in at the LSB (the 'ones' position) will get shifted left 7 times during reading the rest of the 8-character string. After being shifted 7 times it will be in the 'one-hundred-twenty-eights' position in the number. Best advice is try this on paper with short numbers to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

here's how I would do it

```
 int btd(char *str)
 {
    int i , l = strlen(str) , neg = 0;
    int res = 0;

    for(i = 0 ; i < l ; i++)
    {
            if(!i)
            {
                    if(str[i] == '1');
                            neg++;
                    continue;
            }
            if(str[i] == '1')
            {
                    res <<= 1;
                    res |= 1;
            }
            else
                    res <<= 1;

    }
    if(neg)
            res *= -1;
    return res;
 }
```

Comment: This is simple and efficient.